# run command line application from bat file

Tags: batch-file

I am new to bat. I always run blastdbcmd.exe from Win cmd like:

```
cd C:\inetpub\wwwroot\webclient\db\nucleotide
blastdbcmd -entry all -db gss_annot.00 -outfmt %f
```

How can I write a bat file that run the same command?

I try in my bat file:

```
cd C:\inetpub\wwwroot\webclient\db\nucleotide
blastdbcmd -entry all -db gss_annot.00 -outfmt %f > C:\blastdbcmd_out.log 2>&1
```

but, have an error with -outfmt %f. %f is one of the format available for this command and it should be included in the command line

Thanks,

**I resolve the problem by: `-outfmt %%f`.
Thank you @Stephan.**

Comment: try to double the `%`:  `... -outfmt %%f > ...`

Comment: The reason being that in batch files, the percent sign (`%`) has a special meaning (used to reference environment variables, as in `%PATH%`) so if you want a _real_ percent sign (as in your example) you need to double it as Stephan says.

Comment: Please provide a more specific title of your question; you having problems with the `%` sign, so you should probably mention that...